# Open exe from another exe, with certain keys from the internal exe disabled

Tags: c++, c, windows

I have an exe (GUI) that the previous programmer left which was done in cpp, but I need to disable some of the keyboard keys in the program because when they are hit by accident, it is undesirable. I'm using Windows. **Can I write a program that will run an executable on Windows so that certain keystrokes are filtered out?**

Ultimately, I would just want to disable certain keys for my current exe, but I don't have the project files.

Comment: What exactly is "unclear?" Come on guys.

Comment: My reading is that you have a GUI program and you want to disable some keyboard based commands. Is that correct? If so, you should update your question. You should also state what platform you're using.

Comment: The platform is unclear, and makes a big difference. Windows? Mac? X Windows? Etc.

Comment: I didnt know there were exe files on mac or linux.....

Comment: Well, there are executables but they don't have an exe extension. By saying "Windows" you make it clear. I've voted to reopen -- your question seems reasonable to me: "Can I write a program that will run an executable on Windows so that certain keystrokes are filtered out?"

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the help boss.

Comment: No problem. I agree someone should have given you feedback in comments rather than just closing.

Comment: Wow. A locked question that was unlocked. You must live well, for the gods truly favour you. Here's looking for a usable answer. Sadly I don't know of one.

Comment: Your question is still pretty broad. While it may be possible to figure out what the IDs are of the menu items and send messages to the app to disable them, there's no guarantee that the app itself won't enable them again. Look at the case of items on the Edit menu in many apps that are enabled or disabled automatically depending on clipboard content, for instance. I have many apps I've developed that dynamically enable/disable menu and toolbar buttons based on specific conditions at runtiime. There's no generic, one-size-fits-all answer to this question.

Comment: @KenWhite There are other approaches. To disable keys entirely you could inject a DLL.

Comment: Do you not have access to the source code of the application? Is the binary obfuscated or protected? If not, it's probably easier to disassemble it and NOP/JMP out the branches where it looks for those keys.

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach involves injecting a DLL into the process you are creating to hook the function call feeding keystrokes to the existing executable.

You need to figure out what call(s) you need intercept, and then write a function that implements those calls and performs the filtering you need. That call should call the real implementation in the real DLL. Your new DLL contains the filtering call.

I don't have time for a deeper answer now, may revisit later in the day.

Update:

I just had a look through some of my old code (from the late '90s) that injects a DLL to override various calls. It is more advanced that I remembered. The code overrode `GetProcAddress` and the `LoadLibrary*` functions with by iterating through the loaded modules an looking at the PE information. It found the exported symbols, changed the page protection and then updated the address to point to custom functions with hand-coded assembler prologs and epilogs.

Given you have a single target executable, a simpler approach might be to modify the import table and make `GetMessage` and `PeekMesssage` point to your own version of the function that calls the real function but filters out messages with the keys you want to filter.

Changing the import table is probably easier than trying to disassemble the application and NOP out the relevant branches. That way you just have a new DLL and you don't need a separate executable to launch the application. The import table format is documented, unlike your object code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much skill level you have, but you can delete the code in the program.

The code below is not specific GUI environment(MFC or Qt etc..) 
Some programs may include switch statment for handling keyboard events.

```
char inputKey = 'c';
switch(inputKey)
{
  case 'c':
    //do something
    break;
  case 'd':
    //do something
    break;
  default:
    //do something
}
```

If you want to filter out some key, just delete the case in switch statement code.

Answer (score 0):

Given that it's a GUI EXE, that almost certainly means it's a Win32 executable. Keys are delivered to windows as messages, and windows process such messages in a `WindowProc`. You can create wrapper `WindowProc` functions that pre-process these messages and conditionally forward to the message. This is called ["subclassing"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633570(v=vs.85).aspx#subclassing_window).